# Execute AJAX call on .mouseup

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to execute an AJAX call when the users selects an element from a dropdown list. As soon as a `.mouseup` event occurs, I want the AJAX request to fire and submit the data.

Here is what I have:

```
$('<select />')
    .attr('name', 'status')
    .append('<option>Open</option>', '<option>Full</option>', '<option>Canceled</option>')
    .appendTo(this);

$('select[name=status]').mouseup(function () {
    $.ajax({ 
        url: '/ajax/training-update.php',
        data: {status: $currentSelection},
        type: 'POST',
        success: function(output) {
            alert(output);
            }
    });
});
```

This creates an infinite loop when I select an item from the dropdown. What did I do wrong?

EDIT:

As @Kolink suggested below, I changed `.mouseup` to `.change`. This resulted in an infinite loop and an "Illegal Invocation" error.

I tried the test code below to make sure I implemented the `.change` correctly:

```
$('select[name=status]').change(function() {
    alert('Handler for .change() called.');
});
```

This works as expected.

Is there a reason I can't use AJAX with `.change`?

EDIT #2: Full script added

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        var $rowStartDate = $("span[id^=rowStartDate]");
        var $rowEndDate = $("span[id^=rowEndDate]");
        var $location = $(".location");
        var $status = $('.status');
        var $ajaxSubmit = $('#ajaxSubmit');

        $($rowStartDate.add($rowEndDate)).click(function() {
            var $currentSelection = $(this);

            // if there is already an input-field in this TD, return...
            if($currentSelection.find('input').length > 0)
                return;

            $currentSelection.html('');

            $currentSelectionClass = $currentSelection.attr('class');

            //create new input-field-object
            if($currentSelectionClass == "rowStartDate"){
                $('<input type="text" />')
                .attr('name', 'editStartDate')
                .addClass('editStartDate')
                .appendTo(this)
                .datepicker();
            }

            if($currentSelectionClass == "rowEndDate"){
                $('<input type="text" />')
                .attr('name', 'editEndDate')
                .addClass('editEndDate')
                .appendTo(this)
                .datepicker();
            }

       });

        $($location).click(function () {
            var $currentSelection = $(this);

            // if there is already an input-field in this TD, return...
            if($currentSelection.find('select').length > 0)
                return;

            $currentSelection.html('');

            $('<select />')
                .attr('name', 'location')
                .append('<option>Location 1</option>', '<option>Location 2</option>', '<option>Location 3</option>')
                .appendTo(this);
        });

        $($status).click(function () {
            var $currentSelection = $(this);

            // if there is already an input-field in this TD, return...
            if($currentSelection.find('select').length > 0)
                return;

            $currentSelection.html('');

            $('<select />')
                .attr('name', 'status')
                .append('<option>Open</option>', '<option>Full</option>', '<option>Canceled</option>')
                .appendTo(this);

        });

        //AJAX call not working correctly
            $('select[name="status"]').change(function () {
                $.ajax({ 
                    url: '/ajax/training-update.php',
                    data: {status: $currentSelection},
                    type: 'POST',
                    success: function(output) {
                        alert(output);
                        }
                });
            });

       //Original AJAX implementation. Moved to above.
       // $($ajaxSubmit).click(function () {
            // $.ajax({ 
                // url: '/ajax/training-update.php',
                // //data: {action: 'test'},
                // type: 'POST',
                // success: function(output) {
                    // alert(output);
                    // }
            // });
       // });

    // $("#ajaxError").ajaxError(function(event, request, settings){
        // $(this).append("Error requesting page " + settings.url);
    // });

    });
</script>
```

Comment: Why would you use `mouseup`? Even if it did work when selecting the item with the mouse, tt won't fire if someone changes the value with the keyboard.

Comment: @JuanMendes - Good point. That's why I'm raising the question. I'm looking into the `change` event as Kolink suggested below. Thanks.

Comment: Are you changing the value of the `select` in the $.ajax `success` handler?

Comment: @JoãoSilva - No, i'm not. However, that is the next step.

Comment: Can you show the full code for the change handler that causes the infinite loop? It'd be nice to reproduce the problem on http://www.jsfiddle.net

Comment: @JuanMendes - Hi Juan. I added the full script in the original question. Sorry, I can't create a jsfiddle, it's blocked by the network admins here. The part I'm focusing on right now is about 3/4 of the way down. It's `$($status).click(function () {` Thanks for taking the time to help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing your event to `onchange()` that way it only fires when the value selected changes.

Comment: Thanks! I've been trying all sorts of things, but i'm still stuck. I added the full script above.

Comment: I wish I could accept multiple answers since they all helped me.

Answer (score 5):

You should use the `change` event to detect when a `<select>` has been used. `mouseup` is not reliable on that element.

Comment: ok, I'm doing something wrong. I changed `.mouseup` to `.change` and I still get an error "Illegal Invocation". Any ideas?

Comment: I'm also getting this error: "Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded"

Comment: @Paul `.change` is to invoke the event. Use `.onchange` to register the event.

Answer (score 2):

**Regarding the infinite loop**

Since others have already answered the part about changing `mouseup` to `change` I'll just talk about the infinite loop problem:

If your change handler is setting the value of the drop down, that will cause the handler to be run again. Your handler must be smart enough to detect that situation, probably by detecting that the drop down is already in the state you expect and not calling setting the value in that case

Comment: changing the value of an element through code does not trigger the change event.

Comment: @KevinB - Sorry, what do you mean?

Comment: doing `this.value = "foobar"` does not cause a change event, thus it isn't the source of the infinite loop as suggested by Juan Mendes.

Comment: @KevinB That's true, and I was under the impression that calling `$.val('something')` would fire it, but it won't, according to http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/#v=1.7.2&fn=jQuery.fn.val